# How does Perl 6 evaluate truthiness?

Tags: raku, truthiness

In reading about Perl 6, I see a feature being trumpeted about, where you no longer have to do:

```
return "0 but true";
```

...but can instead do:

```
return 0 but True;
```

If that's the case, how does truth work in Perl 6? In Perl 5, it was pretty simple: 0, "", and undef are false, everything else is true.

What are the rules in Perl 6 when it comes to boolean context?

Comment: in Perl 5 it is common to use '0E0' as a 'zero but true' return value

Comment: I'll give you an upvote for use of the worth "truthiness" in a technical question :)

Comment: @PaulDixon: The term is also used in the Ruby community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So to combine what I think to be the best of everyone's answers:

When you evaluate a variable in boolean context, its .true() method gets called. The default .true() method used by an object does a Perl 5-style <0, "", undef> check of the object's value, but when you say "but True" or "but False", this method is overridden with one that doesn't look at the value just returns a constant.

One could conceivable write a true() method which, say, returned true when the value was even and false when it was odd.

Answer (score 18):

Perl 6 evaluates truth now by asking the object a question instead of looking at its value. The value is not the object. It's something I've liked about other object languages and will be glad to have in Perl: I get to decide how the object responds and can mutate that. As ysth said, you could do that in Perl 5 with overload, but I always feel like I have to wash my hands after doing it that way. :)

If you don't do anything to change that, Perl 6 behaves in the same way as Perl 5 so you get the least amount of surprise.

Comment: That'd be more object oriented than Ruby - only `false` and `nil` lack truthiness, and there's nothing you can do about it, unless you monkeypatch `!` and do `!!foo`.

Answer (score 11):

See [Synopsis 12: Roles](http://dev.perl.org/perl6/doc/design/syn/S12.html#Roles).

The rules are the same, but the "but" copies the 0 and applies a role to the copy that causes it to be true in boolean context.

You can do the same thing with overload in Perl 5.

Comment: Er, don't you mean "true in a boolean context"?

Answer (score 11):

Truthness test just calls the `.true` method on an object, so the "mix in" operation `$stuff but True` just (among other things) overrides that method.

This is specified in [S02](http://perlcabal.org/syn/S02.html#Context), generally enum types (of which Bool is one) are described in [S12](http://perlcabal.org/syn/S12.html#Enums).

Answer (score 6):

According to O'Reilly's *[Perl 6 and Parrot Essentials](http://books.google.com/books?id=NYgzEwH5tsQC&pg=PA37&lpg=PA36&ots=cjwHsY0ZrS&output=html)*, **false** is 0, undef, the empty string, and values flagged as *false*. **true** is everything else.

Also, Perl 6 has both a primitive boolean type and by having True and False **roles** that any value can mix in (so you can have a "0 but True" value or a "1 but False" one for example, or a false list containing elements, or a true list that's empty).

See http://www.mail-archive.com/macosx@perl.org/msg09930.html

Comment: That book is ancient and does not represent the current state of the language.

Answer (score 1):

One false value that gets neglected nearly everywhere is "0". I recently made this painful discovery that "0" is **false** in PERL 5.  Gee.  A non-empty string that's false.  I was really hoping that would change in PERL6, but I guess not.

```
> if ( "0" ) { say "True" } else { say "False" }
False
```

The ||= idiom clobbered some strings I really wasn't expecting:

```
$ perl -e '$x = "0"; $x ||= ""; print ">>$x<<\n";'
>><<
```

Comment: That is why [defined-or](http://perltraining.com.au/tips/2008-03-03.html) `//` is so nice. It's enabled (starting in Perl 5.10) by `use 5.010`.

Comment: Oops, I just remembered that since defined-or did not conflict with previous syntax, it is enabled by default.

Comment: This answer was written about P6 prior to its first official release in 2015. `if ( "0" ) { say "True" } else { say "False" }` yields `True`. The P6 compiler rejects the other line at compile-time. With two changes it compiles and produces what I assume @kovacsbv would consider the correct result: `my $x = "0"; $x ||= ""; print ">>$x\<<\n"; # >>0<<`.

Comment: @kovacsbv you got your wish. In the Raku REPL: `put "0".Bool;` returns `True`, while `put "".Bool;` returns `False`. At the command-line, `raku -e 'my $x = "0"; $x ||= ""; put ">>"~$x~"<<";'` returns `>>0<<`. HTH.