# What are the truthy and falsy values in Raku?

Tags: raku, truthiness

While it is always possible to use mixins or method overrides to modify the Bool coercions, *by default* what values are considered to be truthy and what values are considered to be falsy?

Note: this question was [asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125265/how-does-perl-6-evaluate-truthiness), but unfortunately it is so old its content is completely out of date and useless is modern Raku.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are no truthy values, as each type decides for itself via a `.Bool` method that is called in boolean contexts.  For built-in types, the following return **`False`** when their `.Bool` method is called.

- `0` (except `Rat` of `x/0` where `x≠0`)
- Empty list/collection types (List, Array, Hash, Map, Set, Bag, etc)
- Empty string
- `Failure`
- `Promise` prior to being kept/broken.
- `StrDistance` whose before/after is the same.
- `Junction`, when you expect it to.
- Type objects
- Nil (technically type object)
- Any undefined value (technically type objects)

Otherwise, any defined value by default returns **`True`** when its `.Bool` method is called.  This includes the `Str` `'0'`, `NaN`, and zero-length range (`0^..^0`) that in other languages might not be truthy.

This answer is intended as a quick reference.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57793892/3646587) for a more detailed discussion.

Comment: Of course any object can have it's own `.Bool` method and can handle it's own truthiness. 
And if need be you can also use composition to handle the classic DBI case : `0 but True;`

Comment: @Scimon: indeed. I actually wrote this question/answer only because I was doing a blog post on a similar topic and wanted to link to a good overview like what other languages have and realized the SE question for P6 was really out of date. I talk about both of what you mention in the blog ha

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR** This answer is an exhaustive summary based on the relevant doc.<sup>1</sup>

- The base case<sup>2</sup> is `True` for a defined object (an instance) and `False` for an undefined one (a type object).
- Numerically `0` values or `0/0` are `False`. (But a `Rational` with a non-zero numerator eg `1/0` is `True` and `(0/0).Num` (which evaluates to `NaN`) is `True`.)
- An empty collection (`List`, `Hash`, `Set`, `Buf`, etc) is `False`.
- An empty string (eg literal `""`) is `False`. (NB. `"0"`, `"0.0"` etc. are `True`.)
- A defined `Failure` is `False`.
- A defined `Promise` is `False` until its status becomes `Kept`/`Broken`.
- A defined `StrDistance` is `False` if the string transformation it represents had no effect on the string being transformed.
- A defined [`Junction`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Junction) is `True` or `False` depending on the junction's type and the `True`/`False` values of its elements.

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> I wrote the first bullet item based on just knowing it to be true because it's fundamental to P6 and also confirming it by checking the compiler's code.<sup>2</sup> The other bullet points summarize the content at the time of writing this answer of [the `.Bool` doc page](https://docs.perl6.org/routine/Bool) at which point it listed 20 types. If the latter page was incomplete then this answer is incomplete.

<sup>2</sup> The base case can be seen by looking at the Rakudo implementation code, in particular the core's `Mu.pm6`. See [my answer to a similarish SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56725836/1077672) for relevant code links.

Comment: +1 I didn't think the failures and promises. I'll update mine to include those as well. I think having a very reduced quick reference and your detailed answer is a good combination for people looking up things and finding this question