# Raku bug or feature: empty range is True

Tags: raku

```
% raku
Welcome to Rakudo™ v2023.08.
Implementing the Raku® Programming Language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2023.08.

To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
[0] > say so 1..0;
True
```

It would be useful if an empty `Range` would be `False`, but any range is `True`.
Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the truthy and falsy values in Raku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57780757/what-are-the-truthy-and-falsy-values-in-raku)

Comment: See [An empty range is truthy. Design doc specs falsey. In python etc it's falsey.](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/5222). Aiui, in recent Rakudos an empty range should evaluate to `False`, and there are tests in roast to assure it stays that way.

Comment: To be explicit, I'm saying it was a bug, and, assuming I'm right, this SO ought by rights be closed. (But not deleted.) That said, I am not the person who voted to close. I am conservative about drawing such conclusions, and would prefer to sleep on it.

Comment: @Brian61354270, thanks, but that doesn't _really_ answer the question.  It states that “Empty list/collection types” are falsy, but an empty range isn't really one of those.  It's very similar though.

Comment: @raiph, I checked in Rakudo 2023.11 and using the evalbot in the Raku irc channel.  Both   return `True` for `so 1..0`.

Comment: Turns out this is fixed in 6.e.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that this is indeed a bug, and it is fixed in the future 6.e version of Raku.

```
% raku
Welcome to Rakudo™ v2023.08.
Implementing the Raku® Programming Language v6.d.
Built on MoarVM version 2023.08.

To exit type 'exit' or '^D'
[0] > use v6.e.PREVIEW;
Nil
[1] > say so 1..0;
False
```

Comment: Good job I didn't make unwarranted assumptions beyond "I need sleep"! And great job you looked closer. Best of all, you had enough tuits to post this SO and then follow up so we have this on record here at SO. Thank you, and happy rest of AoC despite Raku bugs.  ✌ (And while I'm commenting, thanks to Liz for fixing this and putting it under `6.e` as part of principled backwards compat, and thanks to vrurg et al for years of work continually reifying and tightening Raku's already unusually excellent machinery for back compat and forward fix/enhancement/evolution.)